# Interaction between Webapp and Applet

Tags: java, applet, web-applications

I know that there is a 99% chance of the answer to this question being "no" due to the nature of Applets, but I'm going to ask anyways.

I have a SmartCard containing X.509 certificates and applets. I'd like to be able to interact between the webapp and one of the applets in a read-only manner to pull data via that applet that is unavailable in the certificate.

Again, I know that applets are supposed to be sandboxed, which should prevent such a thing, but I thought I would ask anyways.

Jason

Comment: Applets can talk to each other, Applets can talk to JavaScript, Applets can do Http Calls. What are you missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to fire HTTP requests. An applet is allowed to fire HTTP requests on own domain as obtained by [`Applet#getCodeBase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29).

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "scriptURL");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
// ...
```

Substitute `"scriptURL"` by the path of whatever server side script is listening on the domain, e.g. `"script.php"`, `"servletURL"`, etcetera. You can pass data as request parameters the usual HTTP way.

#### See also:

- [How to use URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)